# Is there a way of specifying a nested generic without specifying a type twice in Java 8+

Tags: java, generics

Given the following example...

S denotes a start Node of ConcreteType A

T denotes a end Node of ConcreteType B

E denotes an Edge with S as start Node and T as end Node

EdgeSet has a set of Edges accessed by an interface methods

SomeObject o returns an EdgeSet interface via a method SomeObject.getEdges();

A class definition defined using generics as follows...

```
    public class EdgeSet<S extends Node, T extends Node, E extends Edge<S, T>> { ... }

    public class SomeObject {

      protected EdgeSet<ConcreteNodeA, ConcreteNodeB, ConcreteEdge<ConcreteNodeA, ConcreteNodeB>> someEdgeSet;

      ...

      public EdgeSet<? extends ConcreteNodeA, ? extends ConcreteNodeB, ? extends ConcreteEdge<? extends ConcreteNodeA, ? extends ConcreteNodeB>> getEdges() { 
        //returns someEdgeSet... 
      }
    }
```

Usage Example...

```
    EdgeSet<? extends ConcreteNodeA, ? extends ConcreteNodeB, ? extends ConcreteEdge<? extends ConcreteNodeA, ? extends ConcreteNodeB>> exampleEdgeSet = o.getEdges();
```

Is there some way of defining this code, and the code which uses the member method without defining things twice?

For example:

`public class EdgeSet<E extends Edge<S extends Node, T extends Node>> { ... }`

`EdgeSet<ConcreteEdge<? extends ConcreteNodeA, ? extends ConcreteNodeB>>`

`protected EdgeSet<ConcreteEdge<ConcreteNodeA, ConcreteNodeB>>`

If not, is there somewhere where you can put through an RFC to reduce redundant information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some way of defining this code, and the code which uses the member method without defining things twice?

Given your `EdgeSet` as you currently define it, the only alternative I see is to use an `Edge` implementation that is non-generic:

```
public class ConcreteEdgeAB extends Edge<ConcreteNodeA, ConcreteNodeB> {
    // ...
}
```

Then you could write declarations such as

```
protected EdgeSet<ConcreteNodeA, ConcreteNodeB, ConcreteEdgeAB> someEdgeSet;
```

That still has some redundancy, however, because `ConcreteNodeA` and `ConcreteNodeB` are the only types you can use for `S` and `T` when you use `ConcreteEdgeAB` as `E`.  Moreover, it's not as flexible is you would probably like.

---

I'm inclined to think that the main problem is that you have over-parameterized.  If your `Edge` type is itself parameterized by the node types of its ends, then it is inherently redundant to parameterize a set of edges on the node types as well -- an *edge* set should need only to be parameterized on the type of edges it contains:

```
interface Edge<S extends Node, T extends Node> {
}

// The bounds on the type parameters of Edge effectively apply here, too:
public class EdgeSet <E extends Edge<?, ?>> {
    // ...
}

public class SomeObject {

    protected EdgeSet<ConcreteEdge<ConcreteNodeA, ConcreteNodeB>> someEdgeSet;

    ...

    public EdgeSet<? extends ConcreteEdge<? extends ConcreteNodeA, ? extends ConcreteNodeB>> getEdges() { 
        return someEdgeSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this looks a great snippet of info with example, the only possible problem I can think of is that EdgeSet stores a reference to an instance of the first node.   

`protected S parentNode;` (as ConcreteNodeA instance)  
`protected Supplier<T> supplier;` (as method-reference passed in to using ::new via Constructor)    

Would Java be able to infer the type of S and T from the parameterized Edge type?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to make your `EdgeSet` do too many things, but I guess there has to be some reason why you're not just using one of the standard `Set` implementations.  In any case, no, if you want `EdgeSet` to refer directly to the types of the nodes belonging to member edges then you do need to parameterize it with those types.  It's not clear to me whether your really do, but if so, you should also consider whether it is essential to also parameterize it with a specific `Edge` type.  At this point I decline to speculate further on your specific needs.

Comment: Hi, yes there is, it's due to constraints on Neo4j's Spring-Data implementation (EdgeSet is actually inherited from ConcurrentHashMap, as I need a Long as the hash, not the object identity, which is how HashSet is implemented).        It simply adds the parentNode (which is needed to maintain consistency), it is used to populate the ConcreteNodeA parameter, and a Supplier (to allow new edges to be created via the interface) which only has about 8 methods

Comment: If I opened up the full HashMap implementation someone could create an Edge within an EdgeSet, (which are composite objects defined within a Node `SomeObject` with a different `parentNode`, I think Neo4j stores the Nodes and the connecting Edge in different Tables, so this is partly how I can totally nullify the risk of misuse during bulk-batch operations (which is what this is for). I hope it rationalises the choices somewhat.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, because it has shown me how I can reduce partly the amount of repeating code, thanks